# Latest (master/snapshot) Spark documentation - either online or run locally

Tags: documentation, apache-spark

Is there a location where the latest spark documentation has been built and is available?

For example the 1.3.0 release candidate branch was cut five days ago but it is not available from the apache site - the newest is the already-in-production 1.2.0.

Even better would be the output of an Amplab Jenkins build. But maybe someone just publishes it regularly on a publicly accessible location?

**Alternatively**  what is the procedure to generate html from the Spark markdown's?  I can easily put up a local webserver to serve them.

Comment: To respond to your first question, there is an open issue to publish artifacts and docs nightly: [SPARK-1517](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1517)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nightly publication of documentation snapshots and build artifacts is on the Spark roadmap; see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1517.

Comment: thx Josh (and Nick Chammas)

Answer (score 0):

For the SECOND part of my question - how to generate the docs locally - the docs/README.md does have instructions.

The result is shown here;

And here we are (notice **localhost:4000** and Spark **version 1.3.0** - which is not released yet)

[image]

The instructions are copied here:

> The markdown code can be compiled to HTML using the [Jekyll
>   tool](http://jekyllrb.com). `Jekyll` and a few dependencies must be
>   installed for this to work. We recommend installing via the Ruby Gem
>   dependency manager. Since the exact HTML output varies between
>   versions of Jekyll and its dependencies, we list specific versions
>   here in some cases:
>
> ```
> $ sudo gem install jekyll
> $ sudo gem install jekyll-redirect-from
> ```
>
> Execute `jekyll` from the `docs/` directory. Compiling the site with
>   Jekyll will create a directory called `_site` containing index.html as
>   well as the rest of the compiled files.
>
> You can modify the default Jekyll build as follows:
>
> ```
> # Skip generating API docs (which takes a while)
> $ SKIP_API=1 jekyll build
> # Serve content locally on port 4000
> $ jekyll serve --watch
> # Build the site with extra features used on the live page
> $ PRODUCTION=1 jekyll build
> ```
>
> ### Pygments
>
> We also use pygments (http://pygments.org) for syntax highlighting in
>   documentation markdown pages, so you will also need to install that
>   (it requires Python) by running `sudo pip install Pygments`.
>
> To mark a block of code in your markdown to be syntax highlighted by
>   jekyll during the compile phase, use the following sytax:
>
> ```
> {% highlight scala %}
> // Your scala code goes here, you can replace scala with many other
> // supported languages too.
> {% endhighlight %}
> ```
>
> ### Sphinx
>
> We use Sphinx to generate Python API docs, so you will need to install
>   it by running `sudo pip install sphinx`.